# why i can't see the new remote branch on my localhost after git fetch --all?

Tags: git, git-fetch

**Hello everyone.**
yesterday, my boss created a new remote branch that i should have after, but when i use `git fetch --all`, on my local host, i just have the ancient branches that i had before, and i can't switch to the new created branch because i can't see it in my local host.

This is a picture to show you what i tried to do:

[image]

so my question is so clear, how can i see the remote branch in my local host ?
*Thanks.*

Comment: Don't use `--all` with `git fetch`: it does not mean what you think it means. (It means "all remotes", and you only have one remote anyway.) It's not that it is *harmful*, it's just misleading you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `git branch` only shows your local branches. Use `git branch -r` to show remote tracking branches, or `git branch -a` to show all brandches.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, after doing `git fetch --all` you must do `git switch NameOfNewBranch` for switching to the new remote branch and to work on it.

Thanks for Korashen !